# Week #3: What should we be doing?

Tags: discussion

Now that two weeks have gone by, what sort of things should we be focusing on as we get ready for public beta? [Official sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266270/concern-over-the-effects-of-3-week-private-betas/266555#266555) make it seem like other stacks need lots of time, so what are we still missing before we go live in a week?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should make the site interesting and welcoming to newcomers so that new people would be interested in joining our project of building a good site.
This can be achieved — partly at least — through the following:

- **We should have questions ranging through our whole scope.**
  For example, if all questions were about classical Latin, a medievalist might find it uninteresting and decide to leave.
  The most important **question types** should be represented.
  If you think there is a type of question we should welcome but do not have yet, ask one.
- **We should have the key information correct on help pages.**
  I don't know when we will have the ability to edit our help pages, but we should be ready to do that the moment we can.
  The pages will probably have to be updated as the beta progresses, but it probably helps to have the key information correct as soon as possible.
  We need **a concise description of our scope** (including examples of question types that are on-topic and off-topic) and **good example questions for the tour**.
- **We should be ready to welcome users that are not fluent in English.**
  The basic thing is to create a meta post or several in Latin.
  Other languages can be added if needed, but I think our main languages should be English and Latin.
  I don't know how (if at all) we should serve users that are new to both English and Latin.
  See [an earlier meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/113/79).
- **We should make resource questions.**
  This should be done in an organized manner before more resource questions starting coming in.
  See [an earlier meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/103/79).
- **We should think who would be good moderators.**
  Everyone should spend a moment and ask themselves if they are able and willing to become moderators.

Comment: How would a post in Latin help someone new to Latin who was not also fluent in English?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer, I have been wondering about that as well. What I had in mind are people who know Latin at a sufficient level to ask a question but have studied little or no English. I don't really know what to do with users who can't communicate in English or Latin. We can add posts in other languages if needed, but I would start with Latin only.