# 2021 Moderator Election: Nominee suggestions

Tags: discussion, election

Our moderator team is growing, and we're [having an election on April 19th](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/501/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election-for-2021) to choose two new moderators for the site. Prior to their own election, the MathOverflow Community ran a post asking its community members to [suggest nominees](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees).

While in the actual election a person nominates themselves, a post like that can help someone feel more confident in doing so by seeing that they have the support of fellow members. If there's someone you'd like to see run, post an answer suggesting them as a potential moderator and why you think they would be great in the role.

To be clear, votes for different answers should not be taken as pre-votes — they should just be viewed as someone agreeing that the suggested member should try for the role. Answers should also be limited to one nominee each.

Comment: I have to emphasize this: **You are very welcome to become a candidate in the election whether or not someone has nominated you below.** I hope this meta question can encourage those who have been nominated but not discourage those that have not. If you are contemplating running for the position, you can also discuss it in [our site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm).

Comment: [The official nomination period has started.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1) If you decide to nominate yourself, please [answer the questionnaire](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/519/79).

Comment: I locked this question so that it represents the status at the time of the election. If anyone wants to discuss the matter further, a separate question is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to nominate [**cmw**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/78/cmw) (previously C. M. Weimer).

He was one of the four people suggested for the role [when we first got our own moderators](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133/79).
He has been active in meta and chat and is highly knowledgeable about our subject matter.

Comment: Does this mean I'm nominated, or is just a suggestion?

Comment: @cmw This is just a suggestion without any official force. You need to nominate yourself at the election page if you want to run.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to nominate [Asteroides](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/9/asteroides) (previously sumelic?).

I really enjoy reading his well-researched, detailed answers and I am sure he'd be a nice addition to our current moderator team!

Comment: Have you considered running yourself? The same description matches your contributions perfectly, and your consistent presence is amply sufficient for the task. I would be happy to see you among the candidates. (Perhaps I should have written this as a separate post, but I felt I should reach you faster to make sure you have time to consider before nominations close.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thank you for your kind words! While I do appreciate your offer, I'm afraid I won't be able to commit to the mod duties properly, primarily because of my schedule and lack of self-discipline :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear you gave it serious thought! I hope we end up getting more candidates so that all slots are filled and the community gets to decide.

Comment: I will not be running, but I just want to say thank you for the encouragement and support! And also say that I appreciate your knowledgeable posts and comments.

Answer (score 9):

I nominate [**Sebastian Koppehel**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/6567/sebastian-koppehel).

He has been active in chat and very knowledgable about the subject matter.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to nominate [**brianpck**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/45/brianpck).

He has been an active contributor from the start.
With consitent activity, a constructive approach shown in past comments, and great knowledge of subject matter, he would make a great moderator.

(I realize this nomination comes a little late as official nominations end in a couple of days. If the score is lower than others, it is because this answer has had less time to accumulate votes.)

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [**TKR**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/40/tkr).

With a long history of active, valuable, and constructive contributions, I think TKR would make a great addition to the moderator team.

(I realize this nomination comes a little late as official nominations end in a couple of days. If the score is lower than others, it is because this answer has had less time to accumulate votes.)

Answer (score 6):

I think [Alex B.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/39/alex-b) would be a great candidate.

He is highly knowledgeable, his contributions are valuable, he is an experienced user, he is active in answers and comments, and he seems fair.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate [**Adam**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/5056/adam).

He has been active in meta and chat with a clear interest in developing the site.
While he is less fluent in Latin than some other potential candidates, I would consider his knowledge clearly sufficient for a moderator.

Comment: Thank you! This is a wonderful community and I intend to throw my hat into the ring once the elections start.