# Moderator candidates answer your questions

Tags: discussion, election

The voting period is now over, so this question has been locked to record the status at the time of the election.
If you have anything to ask or discuss, please create a new meta question.

---

We had [a meta question where you could propose and vote for questions to ask of moderator candidates](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/79).
Now that the nomination to [our first election](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1) has started, it is time to bring the questionnaire to life.

**If you nominate yourself in the election, please answer the following questions in an answer below.**
I have provided a template below which you can copy, paste, and edit.

#### Questions

1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?
2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?
3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.
4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?
5. Optional: Is there anything you would like to mention?

See [the question proposal meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/79) for more background on these questions.
The nominations also come with short description texts.
The question were chosen according to the criteria mentioned in the linked post, according to the situation at the start of the nomination period.

#### Template for answers

You may format your answers freely or copy and paste from the box below:

```
> 1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?

I have studied Latin...

> 2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?

I would...

> 3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.

I have been active in...

> 4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?

I have always wanted to...

> 5. Is there anything you would like to mention?

No, that was all.
```

Comment: Is there a place (or phase of the election) where it is appropriate to ask the candidates questions?

Comment: @brianpck Yes. You can write a comment under the official nomination at the election page. You can also ask under the answers to this questionnaire. It's good to air any concerns and questions so that voters are informed.

Comment: @brianpck Regarding timing: For general questions for all candidates we had the questionnaire question suggestion question but the time for that was before official nominations start. But for asking specific questions of individual candidates this is the perfect time; it is best if all such questions and discussions are available when voting begins.

Comment: @brianpck, I'm surprised not seeing you among the candidates. You still have 12 hours to decide!

Comment: @kkm Haha, I appreciate it! But I'm starting my dissertation now and will need to reserve the right to go dark for weeks at a time :)

Answer (score 11):

> 1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?

I started formally studying Latin back in high school, and continued through university. At this point it's mostly a hobby for me; I enjoy translating and reading ancient texts, even if I'm far from conversationally fluent. Latin is also the focus of some of my current linguistic research, which is fun—surprisingly few computational linguists have much experience with classics, so there's a lot of new territory to explore.

> 2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?

Pretty much the same as I try to take as a user: welcome newcomers, help them fix low-quality questions and answers, and potentially take further action if something serious comes up.

> 3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.

I try to welcome new users and help them improve their first questions, when necessary. Apart from that, not much moderation has seemed necessary recently: we get the occasional bad question which gets voted down, but no major abuse or spam.

> 4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?

I've enjoyed being part of this community for the last several years, so it would be nice to give back to it as a moderator.

> 5. Is there anything you would like to mention?

I'm usually active on the site a few times per day at this point.

Answer (score 9):

Might as well throw my hat in the ring, as was [suggested by Joonas](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/513/2021-moderator-election-nominee-suggestions).

**1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?**

I have studied Latin since high school all the way through the doctorate level. I have been tutoring in Latin since 2007 and have even taught Latin at the undergraduate level at several different universities.

**2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?**

I have a long history of moderation and site management with various fora over the past few decades, so I would be proactive in reviewing the editing and moderator queues, keeping the site organized, and for newcomers demonstrating by example what responses ought to look like.

**3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.**

I have edited posts as necessary, engaged with users in fixing their posts, reviewed suggested edits and closed posts when available, and I have been active in Latin Meta since the creation of this forum.

**4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?**

To quote Faith No More, "Well, it's a dirty job but someone's gotta do it." And while I'm at it, maybe I can effect positive change.

**5. Is there anything you would like to mention?**

> erant in Romana iuventute adulescentes aliquot, nec ii tenui loco orti, quorum in regno libido solutior fuerat, aequales sodalesque adulescentium Tarquiniorum, adsueti more regio vivere. eam tum aequato iure omnium licentiam quaerentes, libertatem aliorum in suam vertisse servitutem inter se conquerebantur

> αὖτις δὲ τὸ Ἑλληνικὸν ἐὸν ὅμαιμόν τε καὶ ὁμόγλωσσον καὶ θεῶν ἱδρύματά τε κοινὰ καὶ θυσίαι ἤθεά τε ὁμότροπα, τῶν προδότας γενέσθαι Ἀθηναίους οὐκ ἂν εὖ ἔχοι.

Comment: +1 for quoting Faith No More.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?

Learning Latin has been a goal of mine for about 20 years, but I only finally started learning about a year and half ago. The credit for this is owed to this Community, and specifically to the [How can I study Latin on my own](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/957/how-can-i-study-latin-on-my-own) question, which lead me to LLPSI.

> 2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?

I would be very effective at welcoming new members and guiding them to resources to help them continue their Latin Language journey. I'm also very active and chat and can lend my own career experience to moderation tasks and discussions.

> 3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.

I have made it part of my daily routine to check review queues and act accordingly, and welcome new users with kind words and links to relevant guidelines when necessary. I also participate in questions on the meta as well as discussions with current moderators within the chat.

> 4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?

This is a special community that stands out not only within Stack Exchange, but also broadly amongst other communities online. It's welcoming, has many knowledgable and helpful members, and has been instrumental in my own progression with Latin. I believe my experience and abilities can be utilized to a greater extent as a moderator.

> 5. Is there anything you would like to mention?

Thank you for reading my answers and considering me, and good luck to everyone else!

Answer (score 4):

**1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?**

Have been read Latin most my life. Usually in the form of the *Lectio Divina* publish by Rome. Studied Latin since high school and never lost my love of this language.

**2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?**

Help in editing, and participate on meta, as well as a myriad of other occasions that may need a moderator’s intervention.

**3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.**

As I mentioned before, I am definitively not that active here, but am willing to step up to the plate and help out the community in moderating the site to remain strong and healthy.

**4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?**

Latin is one of those languages that needs to be more emphasized in our modern culture and this is an awesome place to do that.

**5. Is there anything you would like to mention?**

***Ut in omnibus glorificetur Deus***

Answer (score -3):

**1. What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?**

I have studied Latin since I was an adolescent. I read Latin for my research which is in historical chronology and history of technology.

**2. What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?**

Answering user requests.

**3. How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.**

This would be my first position as an official moderator. I have actively participating in moderating other forums. For example, I have 17 different moderation badges on Stack Overflow, the original Stack Exchange.

**4. Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin Language Stack Exchange?**

To help support education and awareness of the Latin language.

**5. Is there anything you would like to mention?**

Vellem in amicitia sic errārēmus et isti errori nomen virtus posuisset honestum.

Comment: Would you mind responding to the "elephant in the room" question: Why are you running for moderator, given that [you've only been consistently active on this site for less than a week](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/1495/tyler-durden?tab=activity&sort=all)?

Comment: @brianpck I got a message from the system saying that more candidates were needed, and I have been using Stack Exchange for many years, so I think I know how to do it. As I explained in my answer to question #4, the reason why I am running is to help support education and awareness of the Latin language.

Comment: @brianpck I can confirm, an email was sent out. You should run, too.

Comment: @brianpck To be fair, it could also be said he was active for years with a few breaks