# Would a "historical linguistics resources for Latin (and Greek)" question be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

On a fairly regular basis, we get questions about the history and prehistory of Latin (and sometimes Greek), their descent from Indo-European and so forth. There are a few resources that come up again and again in such discussions: for example, Weiss's historical grammar of Latin or de Vaan's etymological dictionary. I was thinking it might be useful to have a single page listing the most important scholarly reference works on the historical linguistics of both languages. I don't mean anything like a full bibliography of this massive topic, of course, but just a list of the most indispensable and frequently used resources.

I'd post a question to this effect, but I'm hesitant because the question-and-answer format doesn't seem exactly suitable: there are many users here who are knowledgeable in this field, and ideally we'd have a list that everyone could add to, rather than a selection of competing answers, since there isn't going to be a "best answer" to such a question. But maybe the format doesn't matter as much as the content, so that a list of answers each mentioning one or more references would be useful too? I'm not sure.

- Would such a list of resources be a useful thing to have at all?
- If so, is posting a question like "What are the most important scholarly resources for Latin and Greek historical linguistics" a good way to go about this, or would some other approach be better?

Comment: I would suggest posting the suggestion [in our list of requests for broad resource requests](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/79). I like this question idea, but I think it's best to take it through the established route.

Comment: Thanks, @JoonasIlmavirta -- I hadn't seen that Meta question.